# ROS2 on Minimal Ubuntu?

Tags: ros2, ros-bouncy

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it possible to run ROS2 on [Minimal Ubuntu](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/09/minimal-ubuntu-released)?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/297087/ros2-on-minimal-ubuntu?/) by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 468 on 2018-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> On Dockerhub, the new Ubuntu 18.04 LTS image is now the new Minimal Ubuntu 18.04 image. Launching a Docker  instance with docker run ubuntu:18.04  therefore launches a Docker instance with the latest Minimal Ubuntu. ([Minimal Ubuntu, on public clouds and Docker Hub](https://blog.ubuntu.com/2018/07/09/minimal-ubuntu-released))

The ROS2 Bouncy docker images are already based on "Minimal Ubuntu". Refer to its Dockerfile [`FROM ubuntu:bionic`](https://github.com/osrf/docker_images/blob/master/ros2/bouncy/ubuntu/bionic/ros-core/Dockerfile#L3) (`ubuntu:18.04` is equivalent to `ubuntu:bionic`). (ROS2 Ardent is not.)

---

Originally posted by [thinwybk](https://answers.ros.org/users/30400/thinwybk/) with karma: 468 on 2018-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Minimal Ubuntu is still Ubuntu. It just provides a minimal set of packages out-of-the-box.

You might just want to try the install instructions of ROS 2 to check if it works. Maybe you will need to install some additional packages which are not mentioned in the instructions. Then it would good to add those to the instructions.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As Minimal Ubuntu is just a stripped down version of Ubuntu it should "just work".

It looks to be very similar to the Ubuntu docker images that we use for development and CI. Based on the ubuntu announcement linked above, the Ubuntu docker image should be identical to Minimal Ubuntu, (though my guess is that we need https://github.com/docker-library/official-images/pull/4564 to be merged and available on DockerHub to be sure).

You will likely need to install a few more packages to bootstrap the distribution. For example you will need to install

```
dirmngr 
gnupg2
lsb-release
```

to your sources to add the ROS apt repository to your sources.

Any other missing dependency would be useful to know and to contribute to the ROS 2 Wiki.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2018-07-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1